# Why are writeStreams not writing the whole content when used in a forEach loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, fetch

I have an array of urls and I'm running a forEach loop on that array to fetch data from each link and then stream the `res.body` to a file. The problem is that files are not complete when code is done. it works fine when there is only one or two links. anyone can explain why that is? Code sample:

```
links.forEach((link, i) => {
fetch(link)
    .then(res => {
        res.body.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`./xml/test-xml-apc${dates[i]}.zip`));
    })
})
```

**UPDATE**: Also I'm using node-fetch

Comment: Likely because `fetch` is async.

Comment: how do you suggest I handle such a case?

Comment: Maybe something like `Promise.all(links.map(....)).then(() => console.log('all done'))`.